# What is the main difference between require() and define() function in dojo and when would we use either?

Tags: javascript, dojo, js-amd, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to learning dojo and I have come across the `require()` and `define()` functions and I can not get my head around either of them. Also, when would I use either of them? A small demo or example would be beneficial. Many Thanks!

Comment: Another good link: [Dojo require() vs. define()](http://g00glen00b.be/dojo-require-vs-define/).  "define()" provides a return value and lazily loads the dependencies.  It's used to define your own custom modules and the dependencies it needs.  "require()"'s main use is importing modules.  Both are synchronous; only require() is non-lazy.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`require` and `define` are part of the asynchronous module definition (AMD) API.

You use `define` to define a module that can be consumed by other code.  Generally, `define` will be used in a javascript file.  The javascript file is defining a module.  All Dojo files use define.

You use `require` when you are not defining a module, but you require modules that have been defined.  Generally, `require` will be used in HTML pages.  The HTML page is not a module, but requires modules to present the page to the user.

AMD API

https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD

Comment: Discovered a symptom of using the wrong one is the callback returning immediately before the code runs... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590618/requirejs-calling-callbacks-before-dependencies-loaded-resolved?rq=1

Comment: when you are defining a new module and you need another module which you had already created , you can use define to require that module