# dojo require different js files

Tags: dojo, undefined, return-value, require

recently I have a problem about including other js files using dojo. e.g. :
In my 1.js file, I wrote:

```
require(["dijit/form/Button"], function(Button){
addButton(someWidget);});
```

and in my 1a.js file, I wrote the function addButton:

```
function addButton(target){
    var b1=new Button({
        style: "border: 1px solid green",
        label: "xxxxx"
    });
    target.addChild(b1);
    return b1;
}
```

for 1a.js there must be an error, because I did not require that module, but i add require, the biggest
problem is that returned value, I can not get the return value, because of nested funciton.

how can i wrote a js file, which i wrote all my functions, and in another js file, i just call these functions with `dojo require("xxxx", function(x){})`

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojo.require` is the legacy (<=1.6) loader for the toolkit.  Using `dojo.require` in one file, made the code available to all files.

Dojo has moved to using the AMD API for loading modules. In 1a.js, you will also need to add the `require` statement.

My answers to the following questions will provide a better understanding of the AMD API and the `require` statement:

- [What is the main difference between require() and define() function in dojo and when would we use either?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559270/what-is-the-main-difference-between-require-and-define-function-in-dojo-and/11559708#11559708)
- [Dojo Builds...? What now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922618/dojo-builds-what-now/12922801#12922801)
- [What is the purpose of function in the dojo require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130450/what-is-the-purpose-of-function-in-the-dojo-require/15134668#15134668)